# Unable to import a blender scene into three.js

Tags: three.js, blender

I'm trying to import the simpliest Blender scene (camera included) into three.js, but whatever set of options I mark when exporting I always get an exception (data is undefined) when doing the "loader.parse" of the file content (a json string or event an already parsed object) and nothing is shown.
What can be wrong? Is it a bug?

Im using the latest threejs version from github and blender 2.72.
This is what the console.log of the JSON parsed file looks like:

Object { urlBaseType: "relativeToScene", metadata: Object, objects: Object, geometries: Object, materials: Object, embeds: Object, transform: Object, defaults: Object }

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inspected the code step by step and it seems that the Blender plugin is outdated, the expected data structure at many points for the current version of three.js loaders is quite different then tue data structure returned by the plugin.

**EDIT: It's already working in the dev branch!** :D
[enter link description here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5859)